# Correct use of sscanf_s

Tags: c++11, scanf

I'm trying to parse a string into a char and multiple floats in the following format:

```
v 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
```

Originally using `sscanf` I could do so with:

```
char b;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
float z = 0.0f;
int result = sscanf(lineHeader,"%c %f %f %f", &b, &x, &y, &z);
```

However, I'm trying to eliminate an unrelated problem which requires me to use `sscanf_s`.

If I simply change the code to:

```
int result = sscanf_s(lineHeader,"%c %f %f %f", &b, &x, &y, &z);
```

I get an exception stating an unsigned integer is expected. Does `sscanf_s` use different formatting to parse strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), `sscanf_s`'s `%c` conversion specifier requires an additional parameter to check for the buffer size:

```
int result = sscanf_s(lineHeader,"%c %f %f %f", &b, rsize_t{1}, &vertex.x, &vertex.y, &vertex.z);
//                               It's a single char ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.

Comment: @IanYoung almost. I forgot the cast to `rsize_t` :)